# SQL: Distinct Medications to Columns Using Pivot

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot

I know that this question has been asked many times over but since I'm quite new to SQL, it's a bit difficult to modify previous answers for my purposes. I've mostly worked things out but I'm having a ton of difficulty getting a pivot to work while excluding duplicate cases. The issue is that I'm not familiar enough with the syntax quite yet to appropriately tweak things.

I currently have data that looks something like this (simplistic version):

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| **Medication**        | **Patient_ID**                 | 
----------------------------------------------------------
| Amlopidine            |  100123                        |
----------------------------------------------------------
| Lisinopril            |  100123                        |
----------------------------------------------------------
| Eprosartan            |  200415                        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

And I'm hoping for something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| **Patent_ID**         | **MED_1**                      |  **MED_2**        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 100123               |  Amlopidine                     |  Lisinopril       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 200415               |  Eprosartan                     |   NULL            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The issue I'm having is that patients might have had the same medications prescribed many times over the years resulting in a table with loads of duplications which is what I'm trying to avoid.

My code so far (IndicatorValue = Medication):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    FROM 
                    (
                      SELECT row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Patient_ID
                                                ORDER BY IndicatorValue) rn
                      FROM dbo.DiseaseCaseIndicator
                    ) t
                    cross join 
                    (
                      select DISTINCT 'IndicatorValue' col 
                    ) c
                    group by col, rn
                    order by rn, col
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Patient_ID,' + @cols + '  
             from
             (
                select Patient_ID,
                  col+''_''+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
                  value
                from
                (
                  select DISTINCT IndicatorValue, Patient_ID, 


                    row_number() over(partition by Patient_ID
                                      order by IndicatorValue) rn
                  from dbo.DiseaseCaseIndicator WHERE Patient_ID IN (SELECT Patient_ID FROM dbo.HTPatients) AND IndicatorType = ''Medication'' AND Disease = ''Hypertension'' 
                ) d
                cross apply
                (
                  values (''IndicatorValue'', IndicatorValue)
                ) c (col, value)
            ) t
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Pretty rough, I know, but I have a lot of SQL yet to learn!

So the major issues would involve removing those brutal duplicates. Also, I have a ton of columns because I'm still not too clear how the row_number() function is being implemented. I know that I will only need 10 columns max for the meds since only a handful of patients have that many unique medications. Also: the reason for this table format is because of a supervisor request.

If you guys can provide any insight it would be hugely appreciated!!

Comment: Try your queries outside of dynamics. In the first query - why are you partitioning and grouping right after that? Cross join with a constant is equal to `QUOTENAME('IndicatorValue_'+`

Comment: Like I said Ivan, I'm not particularly familiar with SQL and am attempting to tweak a previous answer that was similar. I get results, just not absent of duplicates. I will add in your suggestion though. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I realized what is groupby's purpose - I'd recommend to switch it to `DISTINCT` 'cause you're not actually aggregating anything. Without groupby and cross join that part will look much clearer.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thanks much Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    Patient_ID' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn) +' THEN Medication END) AS ' 
+ QUOTENAME('MED_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn)) + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Patient_ID ORDER BY Medication)
    FROM tbl
) t

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Patient_ID ORDER BY Medication)
    FROM tbl
) t
GROUP BY t.Patient_ID
ORDER BY t.Patient_ID'

PRINT (@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Giving this a shot now. And thanks much for the link.

Comment: Shoot, no dice either... Thanks for your answer either way!

Comment: Felix, trying it out now but running into some issues with the SQL tags: Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: Just made another update. Added declaration: `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''`

Comment: You rock, no more duplications. Thanks a ton for that. One slight issue though - a ton of NULL fields interspersed throughout the data output. Any idea why? 

P.S: I added this to the select statement "WHERE Patient_ID IN (SELECT Patient_ID FROM dbo.HTPatients) AND IndicatorType = ''Medication'' AND Disease = ''Hypertension'' "

Comment: That's expected when you have patients with more medications than the others. There'll be no NULL fields if all patients have the same number of distinct medications.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it - it must be because of the DENSE_RANK(). Totally cool. Thanks again Felix!

Comment: Cool, good to know :) I'll also vote up your answer once I have reputation haha. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic SQL query that will pivot based on aggregation:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT [Patient_ID]'
+ STUFF((SELECT ', MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CAST([RN] AS NVARCHAR) + ' THEN [Medication] END) Med' + CAST([RN] AS NVARCHAR)
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Patient_ID] ORDER BY [Medication]) [RN]
        FROM tblName) A
    GROUP BY [RN]
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '')
+ ' FROM (SELECT [Medication], [Patient_ID], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Patient_ID] ORDER BY [Medication]) [RN]
    FROM tblName) A
GROUP BY [Patient_ID]'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

The idea being to output the CASE aggregation in the stuff statement.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Still getting a load of duplicates. This does help with my understanding though so thanks!